# Song change notification for shoutcast (on android)

Tags: android, metadata, audio-streaming, android-mediaplayer, shoutcast

Using the native Android MediaPlayer class I am able to play Shoutcast streams. Furthermore, using streamscraper (http://code.google.com/p/streamscraper/) I am able to get the metadata for the current playing song in the stream.

I would like to know if there is a way to be notified when the song in the radio stream changes, using my current setup (MediaPlayer and streamscraper).

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be grateful.

Comment: Save the current track in a variable and when it changes, do something?

Comment: Yeah, silly me. This is what I ended up doing. Thanks.

Comment: can you share your code  which expalains how to play radio from southcast and retrieve the metadata.

Comment: @Brad How to save the current track in a variable? can you share some piece of code for doing it?

Comment: @Nishant Look up the page on streamscraper. Given the shoutcast URL it is pretty straightforward to obtain the metadata of the current playing song.

Comment: @Nishant Regarding harvesting shoutcast metadata and comparing for change, take a look at this: http://pastebin.com/dCAuMN7e.

Now, for polling the metadata, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019690/calling-async-task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding harvesting shoutcast metadata and comparing for change, take a look at this: pastebin.com/dCAuMN7e. Now, for polling the metadata, see this: stackoverflow.com/questions/10019690/calling-async-task.

The above two steps solve the question (I am polling the metadata at a fixed time interval and checking if the data has changed).

Answer (score 0):

Write a service class for saving current song and check it with next song.. when the song changes to next song you can use notification..

Thanks..

Comment: I am sorry, but could you please elaborate. How do I save the current song from a stream and how (and when) do I check it with the next song since I don't even know when the next song will start.